# How to search a row for a string and then select the column of that string in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working in VBA trying to select a column based on the occurrence of a certain string in the first row of an excel spreadsheet. First, I am trying to get the code to search for the term "type" in the first row of the spreadsheet, and then select the entire "type" column. From there I've been trying to set that column to a variable so I can call it later on in the code. Sorry I'm not allowed to post the code I've been working as it is for work and not allowed.

Ok, here's the code that I have so far. It searches the first row for "type" and finds that cell and selects it. I'm having trouble tying to assign the variable myCol to the entire column. I keep getting a "Object doesn't support this property or method error". Sorry if this is an obvious fix, but I'm really new to VBA.

```
Function ColSearch() As Integer

Sheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Select
Sheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Unprotect

Dim myCol As Range

    Cells.Find(What:="type", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Set myCol = ActiveCell.EnitreColumn

ColSearch = myCol

End Function
```

EDIT: Ok here's my edited code for searching the columns, selecting the one labelled type, and then setting it equal to a variable. Now I get a "Object variable or With block variable not set" error every time I run it.

```
Function ColSearch() As Range

Sheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Select
Sheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Unprotect

Dim myCol As Range

myCol = Worksheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Cells.Find(What:="type", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Column

myCol = ColSearch

End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro to do the first parts (searching and selecting)?  Once you have that down, you should have enough to try the second part (set the column to a variable).  You don't have to post all of your code, just the part(s) that you're stuck at.

Comment: *Sorry I'm not allowed to post the code I've been working as it is for work and not allowed.*  There is nothing proprietary or confidential about the range `.Find` method, nor assigning its resulting object to a `Range` variable...

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Just post the part of the code that is failing with explanation of how it is failing (expected results, actual results).  Or develop a shortened version that you can post that will clearly demonstrate the problem.  We don't want you to post the entire code.

Comment: Ok I added some more info that hopefully helps explain the issue

Comment: Realized I spelled EnitreCell wrong in the code. I fixed that and now I get a "type mismatch" error

Comment: Re: spelling error: use `Option Explicit` and compile your code.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
Function ColSearch2() As Integer
ColSearch2 = Worksheets("CS-CRM Raw Data").Cells.Find(What:="type", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Column        
End Function
```

The problem is in using "EntireColumn".

According to the documentation, "Returns a Range object that represents the entire column (or columns) containing the specified range. Read-only.", not the column index.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa199727(v=office.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa199727%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

EDIT: Just saw your edit in the main thread. The type mismatch is you return the Range object as an integer.

Comment: I've tried what you had and added my edited code to the original post. I still can't seem to get it to work, as I get a "Object variable or With block variable not set" error. Again, sorry if this is a simple problem but I'm very new to this.